# I don't know how to grab a specific link from a nested dictionary from an API (Using PythonI)

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

So I'm practicing using API's and I'm using Pexel's API to get images from their site. Its working fine and I'm able to get a list of everything they're showing me (see the first segment of code):

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": access_key
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"query": "Dragon"})

print(response.json())
```

[Output Image][1]
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYcYF.png

When I slightly alter the code to get the name and the link to the pexel posting (second image), that works fine too:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": access_key
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"query": "Dragon"})

dogs = (response.json()["photos"])

for dog in dogs:
    print(dog["alt"], dog["URL"])
```

[Output Image][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf3G5.png

The problem I have is that when I just do `print(response.json())`, it will show me a dictionary of all the data it's giving me and it also shows various sizes (**Keys**) that are connected to URL links for me to pick from (original, large, medium, small, etc). I want to just print the original-size link(**Key**), but the problem is that the *original* URL link(**Key**) is inside a dictionary, that's inside of a list, that's inside of the overall API dictionary (picture below/Pexels better picture documentation of the structure):

[Output Image][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0cp9.png

[Pexel Documentation Image][4]
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iakry.png

How would I write the code out to get that Original URL link instead? I tried writing out this code but it didn't work:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": access_key
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"query": "Dragon"})

dogs = (response.json()["photos"])

for dog in dogs:
    print(dog["alt"], dog["src: {"original"}"])
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of text. Paste as formatted text.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? I'm still kinda new to stackoverflow

Comment: The same way you posted your code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out now. You have to use two `[]` side by side with each other as shown below:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": access_key
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"query": "Dragon"})

dogs = (response.json()["photos"])

for dog in dogs:
    print(dog["alt"], dog["src"] ["original"])
```